# RSA fingerprints on github don't match ssh-keygen

Tags: github, ssh

Looking at the fingerprints on github and of my public ssh key they have different formats (e.g. colon separator) and differ

```
Github
a6:f2:09:40...etc

As generated by: ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/key.pub
4096 SHA256:neLNT0...etc
```

I can login so can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

The current OpenSSH is using SHA256 hashes instead of the ancient MD5 you expect on the first line of your code. To get the legacy fingerprint, there is the `-E` switch to select a hash algorithm:

```
ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf ~/.ssh/key.pub
```